# foreign key problem in postgres' logical replication in django

Tags: django, postgresql

I configured postgres logical replication between several DBs in my django project to replicate common data like django_content_types, comments etc. from primary db to peripheral DBs. There is no master or slave DBs though, because data from peripheral DBs is also replicated in primary DB. I call it primary because I have some basic data in it.
And I use django-viewflow application, so instances of viewflow app are read from primary db. But I have models inherited from django-viewflow's models and they are read from perpheral DBs. The system is like as below:

```
class Process(models.Model): # django-viewflow model, read from primary


class SomeProcess(Process):  # inherited model, read and written into another DB
```

Also there is a model called Task, that has a foreign key to process and a self-referencing field called "previous" and there is a table called viewflow_task_previous, that has task_ids like this:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    process = models.ForeignKey(Process, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Process'))
    previous = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, related_name='leading',
                                  verbose_name=_('Previous'))
```

Naturally I use django routers.
So the problem is that when task object is created in peripheral DB it is replicated to primary, but viewflow_task_previous table is only read from primary db, so sometimes task data is not in time to replicate to primary db and IntegrityError is raised with message:

```
    insert or update on table "viewflow_task_previous" violates foreign key constraint "viewflow_task_previous_to_task_id_fk_viewflow_task_id"
DETAIL:  Key (to_task_id)=(some id) is not present in table "viewflow_task".
```

This happens rarely, but happens. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Do you mean that the viewflow_task_previous table is _written_ to the primary DB?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that. From peripheral only viewflow_task and viewflow_process are replicated to primary, viewflow_task_previous is written and read from primary db, it is not replicated to peripheral.

Comment: If you read and write the through table `viewflow_task_previous` on the peripheral DB would that solve your issue?

Comment: viewflow_task_previous is only written to primary db, because it is viewflow's model. When I first configured the logical replication I added viewflow_task_previous to publication on primary db. But I found out that it was pointless. Now viewflow_task_previous table has no records at all in peripheral dbs.

Comment: viewflow_task is written to the peripherals and it's the only other table that viewflow_task_previous has a relationship too, isn't it a viewflow' model too? Writing them to different DBs seems a bit odd

Comment: It's because of models that I inherit from viewflow_process, I write a record to peripheral, so the related fields like viewflow_task are also written to peripheral.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with router:

```
class PrimaryRouter:

def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    return 'default'

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    if model._meta.model_name == 'task_previous':
        db = hints.get('instance')._state.db
        return db
    return 'default'
```